# Changing the lighting for all scenes

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a simple game setup with multiple scenes. I would like to change the lighting settings for all scenes at once, but I do not see a way to do this. I am stuck making the same changes for every scene individually. Help?

Comment: Are you doing this via script or..?

Comment: @Draco18s no in the Lighting settings window in editor

Comment: No, no there is not a way to do this. Not without writing a custom editor script.